# about list in python

Tags: python, list

I wrote `ans = [[0,0],[0,0]]`. Then `ans[0][0]` is 0. But me writing `ans[0][0] += 1`, it was changed to `[[1,0],[1,0]]`. Please tell me why it is.

I wrote like this
`ans = [[0,0],[0,0]] ans[0][0] += 1`
I supposed it's change to `[[1,0],[0,0]]`, because `ans[0][0]` is 0.
However it was change to `[[1,0],[1,0]]`.
I'd like you to tell me what the correct way to write it is.

Comment: You didn't write `ams = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]`. If you would, this wouldn't have happened. You probably wrote something that you think is equivalent (e.g. `[[0, 0]] * 2`) but it is not, because it does not copy the inner list, only reference to it.

Comment: please add minimum reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. 


Your issue is not reproducible, you probably write different code
```
>>> ans = [[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> ans
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> ans[0][0] += 1
>>> ans
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: I wrote like this   'ans = [[0]*(6//3)]*(6//3)'  and ' ans[1//3][1//3] +=1', and it's changed to '[[1, 0], [1, 0]]'

Comment: may you miss something typo

Comment: *what the correct way to write it is.* This is the correct way to write it, since this code doesn't reproduce the issue you are describing.

Comment: @Habor so as @Chayim said, you didn't write `ans = [[0,0],[0,0]]` you wrote `ans = [[0]*(6//3)]*(6//3)` instead. You might want to edit your question and put the code you actually have

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote like this 'ans = [[0]*(6//3)]*(6//3)' and ' ans[1//3][1//3]
> +=1', and it's changed to '[[1, 0], [1, 0]]' –

That is not equals to `ans = [[0,0],[0,0]]`. Both `ans[0]` and `ans[1]` are pointing to the same list. I believe it's because you do `[[0, 0]] * 2`, it points to the same list reference, you can confirm if 2 objects pointing to same place with

```
>>> id(ans[0])
4336826632
>>> id(ans[1])
4336826632
```

Here's a simplified version of your issue:

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a   # both b and a are referring to the same place in memory
>>> b[0] += 1  # doing this is same as referencing using a, i.e a[0] += 1
>>> a
[1]
```

Comment: I'm so grateful. Because of you, I solved and know python more